# How to pass date format Response to SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: android, simpledateformat, date-format, date-formatting

I am getting Date Formate Response like `11:10 AM  Thursday - March, 02 2017`.

i have tried like this

```
 String time = 11:10 AM  Thursday - March, 02 2017
   try {


 Date cDate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa EEE - MMM, dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(time);
                    System.out.println(cDate);

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(cDate);
                    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

                    String monthName = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH).format(cal.getTime());
                    String day = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(cal.getTime());
                    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd", Locale.ENGLISH).format(cal.getTime());
                    String hour = new SimpleDateFormat("hh", Locale.ENGLISH).format(cal.getTime());
                    String min = new SimpleDateFormat("mm", Locale.ENGLISH).format(cal.getTime());
                    String am_pm = new SimpleDateFormat("a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(cal.getTime());

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But it goes in exception saying:

> Unparseable date: "11:10 AM  Thursday - March, 02 2017" (at offset 9)

So how to pass Date Format like this String?

Comment: try using `EEEE` instead of `EEE`. I'm not sure it would work, but since `EEE` is for shorten day of week (e. g. Tue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just missed one small thing.

you are using like :

```
Date cDate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa EEE - MMM, dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(time);
```

instead, you need to use like this

```
Date cDate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa  EEE - MMM, dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(time);
```

**You missed the one extra space of Thursday**

Comment: @NiteshRathod.. if this solved your issue then please accept this answer

Comment: do you know how to convert  this date   Fri Mar 03 02:24:21 GMT+12:00 2017  device time.

Answer (score 0):

Use EEEE for full name like Thursday

```
Date cDate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa EEEE - MMM, dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(time);
```

Comment: i have tried but it says :Unparseable date: "12:17 PM  Thursday - March, 02 2017" (at offset 9)